# $f(x)=e^{-|x|} \text{ and }g(\theta)= \int_{-1}^{1} f(\frac{x}{\theta}) dx$ , then find $\lim\limits_{\theta \to 0} \frac{g(\theta)}{\theta}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification, definite-integrals

> if
> $$
> f(x)=e^{-|x|} 
> \quad\text{and}\quad 
> g(\theta) = \int_{-1}^{1} f \Bigl(\frac{x}{\theta}\Bigr)\, dx,$$ then find
> $$
> \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{g(\theta)}{\theta}. 
> $$

my attempt

first, I'm going to try to determine $g(\theta)$

let
$$
\frac{x}{\theta} = \ln(y) 
\quad\text{so}\quad 
\frac{dx}{\theta} = \frac{dy}{y}
$$

so the limits now are $e^{-\frac{1}{\theta}}$ and $e^{\frac{1}{\theta}}$
so
$$
g(\theta) = \int_{\frac{1}{e^\theta}}^{\frac{1}{e^{-\theta}}} \frac{dy}{y^2} 
$$
so
$$
g(\theta) = \theta \, \Bigl({\frac{1}{e^{-\theta}}} - {\frac{1}{e^{\theta}}} \Bigr)
$$

from which I conclude the limit is $0$.

Am I right, if not, where am I going wrong?

Source: ISI 2021 UGA

Comment: You are completely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{g(\theta)}{\theta} = \frac{1}{\theta}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x/\theta) \ dx =\frac{1}{\theta}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{-|x/\theta|} \ dx$$
Suppose $\theta > 0$. Then,
$$\frac{g(\theta)}{\theta} = \frac{2}{\theta}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x/\theta} \ dx = 2\int_{0}^{1/\theta}e^{-x} \ dx = 2(1-e^{-1/\theta})$$
Suppose $\theta < 0$. Then,
$$\frac{g(\theta)}{\theta} = \frac{2}{\theta}\int_{0}^{1}e^{x/\theta} \ dx = 2\int_{0}^{1/\theta}e^{x} \ dx = 2(e^{1/\theta} - 1)$$
Taking the sided limits, we have that
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0^{+}}\frac{g(\theta)}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0^{+}}2(1 - e^{-1/\theta}) = 2$$
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0^{-}}\frac{g(\theta)}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0^{-}}2(e^{1/\theta} - 1) = -2$$
The limit then does not exist.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you need to fix some typographical errors.  Your first equation states $f(x/\theta) = e^{-|x|/\theta}$ which is not actually true unless $\theta > 0$; it should read $f(x/\theta) = e^{-|x/\theta|}$.  Also, you typed $-x/t$ and $x/t$ in the second and third lines when it should be $-x/\theta$ and $x/\theta$.  Then in the final conclusion, you wrote $$\lim_{\theta \to 0^+} \frac{g(\theta)}{\theta} = \lim_{\theta \to 0^-} \ldots,$$ where you meant to write $\lim_{\theta \to 0^+}$ on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out @heropup

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand why my $g(\theta)$ is wrong, mind explaining please